# 8 Columns in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I set up 8 equal columns in the latest version of Twitter bootstrap.

I can create 4 equal columns by doing the following but don't get how I can get 8:

```
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-6">
                    <a href="#"><img src="/image.png" class="img-responsive" alt="..."></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-6">
                    <a href="#"><img src="/image.png" class="img-responsive" alt="..."></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-6">
                    <a href="#"><img src="/image.png" class="img-responsive" alt="..."></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-6">
                    <a href="#"><img src="/image.png" class="img-responsive" alt="..."></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I had the same issue. While still using Bootstrap I'm now also using another css grid library, solely for gridding (http://thisisdallas.github.io/Simple-Grid/)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                            1
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                            2
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                            3
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                            4
                </div>
          </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                            5   
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                            6
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                            7
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                            8
                </div>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you give some explanation about your solution ?

Comment: dividing to two equal columns, i.e 2 "col-xs-6" then further dividing each "col-xs-6" to 4 equal columns. i.e "col-xs-3" we have 8 equal columns.

Answer (score 25):

I know that this is a pretty old topic, but it's the top search result for this problem, so I hope it's ok that I come through with an answer that I think is better than any of the current options provided here.

In an n-column layout, I don't want to have to finagle some weird `.row` `.col-` stuff that doesn't allow me to resize when I move down in breakpoints.

For instance, the current accepted answer here correctly points out that you can't do this with default bootstrap, but the next answer in line suggests that you nest `.col-xs-3`'s inside of `.col-xs-6`'s and I assume a lot of people coming here are using that because it is the only workable answer you can find in the first page of a google search.

What if I want 8 columns on the `lg` breakpoint and then 4 columns on tablets and 2 columns on mobile? That answer does not degrade gracefully. This method will, and it's incredibly easy to implement.

First, add this to your CSS file:

```
.col-xs-8r,
.col-sm-8r,
.col-md-8r,
.col-lg-8r {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.col-xs-8r {
    width: 12.5%;
    float: left;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .col-sm-8r {
        width: 12.5%;
        float: left;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .col-md-8r {
        width: 12.5%;
        float: left;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .col-lg-8r {
        width: 12.5%;
        float: left;
    }
}
```

Next, add `col-*-8r` to your columns like so:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-8r">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, you have an 8 column layout that can work on all breakpoints.

The cool thing about this method is that if you need some odd number of columns, it's very easy to extend this out. You simply divide 100 by however many columns you need and then use that number in place of the 4 instances of `width: 12.5%;` in the code above (obviously, don't forget to update the class names to whatever number you are using).

For instance, if you need a 7 column layout, you would use the absurdly long `width: 14.28571428571429%` in place of those 4 instances, change your class names to be `.col-*-7r` and then you can drop the class name in anywhere you want.

Comment: Based on @Cory's solution I created [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/hughanderson4/65e066203922d0cce285eaed2f7ba4ac) with full Css for Bootstrap grid in 10ths and 8ths.  I use Css calc to prevent from using repeating decimals.

Comment: Beautiful simple and GREAT explanation for extending! Thank you!

Comment: Any reason why you added the `r` in `col-x08r`?

Comment: The solution works great. I hope one day the Grid System evolves to adjust automatically.

Answer (score 17):

Add a style like this in to the bootstrap stylesheet, style.css:

```
.col-8{
width: 12.5%;
}
```

Then add it to your html.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-8"></div>
<div class="col-8"></div>
<div class="col-8"></div>
<div class="col-8"></div>
<div class="col-8"></div>
<div class="col-8"></div>
<div class="col-8"></div>
<div class="col-8"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This would override Bootstrap's `.col-8` class and possibly mess up any other views you have using that class.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem and went 4 columns, each containing 2 nested columns.

Answer (score 4):

### Update 2020 - Bootstrap 4

The question is very applicable to Bootstrap, but the accepted answer is now out-of-date.

The simple method to get 8 equal columns is to use the [auto-layout columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns)...

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">1</div>
        <div class="col">2</div>
        <div class="col">3</div>
        <div class="col">4</div>
        <div class="col">5</div>
        <div class="col">6</div>
        <div class="col">7</div>
        <div class="col">8</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/ds99xlkSGa

Answer (score 2):

For 8 column grid you don't have to customize the css or html.

Simply create or copy this:

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-3">1</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">2</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">3</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">4</div>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-3">5</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">6</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">7</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">8</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This seems to be almost identical to Niran Manandhar's solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                <div class="premiumAtLifeRightBorder">
                    <p><b>Make</b></p>
                    <p class="marginTop20">Nissan</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                <div class="premiumAtLifeRightBorder">
                    <p><b>Model</b></p>
                    <p class="marginTop20">Tiara-5</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                <div class="premiumAtLifeRightBorder">
                    <p><b>Engine no</b></p>
                    <p class="marginTop20">102354</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                <div class="premiumAtLifeRightBorder">
                    <p><b>Chassis no</b></p>
                    <p class="marginTop20">2114-14</p>
                </div>
            div>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                <div class="premiumAtLifeRightBorder">
                    <p><b>Mfg Year</b></p>
                    <p class="marginTop20">2016</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                <div class="premiumAtLifeRightBorder">
                    <p><b>Seats</b></p>
                    <p class="marginTop20">5</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                <div class="premiumAtLifeRightBorder">
                    <p><b>Body Type</b></p>
                    <p class="marginTop20">Sedan</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                <div>
                    <p><b>CC</b></p>
                    <p class="marginTop20">3900</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As BenM said above, Bootstrap uses a 12 column grid system, which won't divide cleanly into 8 equal columns.

If you absolutely require 8 columns, it might be worth checking out [this](http://grids.heroku.com/), or even [rolling your own](http://css-tricks.com/dont-overthink-it-grids/).

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this steps to achieve 8 column in bootstrap.

```
<!-- 8 Column -->
<div class="8-column">
    <!-- Container -->
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Parent row -->
        <div class="row">
            <!-- 1st parent column -->
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <!-- Child row -->
                <div class="row">
                    <!-- 1st Child Column -->
                    <div class="col-md-6">

                    </div>
                    <!-- /1st Child Column -->
                    <!-- 2nd Child Column -->
                    <div class="col-md-6">

                    </div>
                    <!-- /2nd Child Column -->
                </div>
                <!-- Child row -->
            </div>
            <!-- /1st parent column -->
            <!-- 2nd parent column -->
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <!-- Child row -->
                <div class="row">
                    <!-- 1st Child Column -->
                    <div class="col-md-6">

                    </div>
                    <!-- /1st Child Column -->
                    <!-- 2nd Child Column -->
                    <div class="col-md-6">

                    </div>
                    <!-- /2nd Child Column -->
                </div>
                <!-- Child row -->
            </div>
            <!-- /2nd parent column -->
            <!-- 3rd parent column -->
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <!-- Child row -->
                <div class="row">
                    <!-- 1st Child Column -->
                    <div class="col-md-6">

                    </div>
                    <!-- /1st Child Column -->
                    <!-- 2nd Child Column -->
                    <div class="col-md-6">

                    </div>
                    <!-- /2nd Child Column -->
                </div>
                <!-- Child row -->
            </div>
            <!-- /3rd parent column -->
            <!-- 4th parent column -->
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <!-- Child row -->
                <div class="row">
                    <!-- 1st Child Column -->
                    <div class="col-md-6">

                    </div>
                    <!-- /1st Child Column -->
                    <!-- 2nd Child Column -->
                    <div class="col-md-6">

                    </div>
                    <!-- /2nd Child Column -->
                </div>
                <!-- Child row -->
            </div>
            <!-- /4th parent column -->
        </div>
        <!-- /Parent row -->
    </div>
    <!-- /Container -->
</div>
<!-- /8 Column -->
```

Answer (score -1):

Best way to deal with this is to create table and divide the section with `vw` and then use bootstrap grid inside it.

My example is I wanted to divide layout into 63:37 ratio and again divide first part into 3 parts and second into two parts.

So I created table with two columns with width `63vw` and `37vw` then use bootstrap grid inside it respectively.

```
<div class="row">
<table id="main_table" style="width: 100%;height: 100%" cellspacing="0">
    <tr style="width: 100%; position: relative">
        <td id="donut1" style="width: 63vw;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    Loading
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    Loading
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    Loading
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td id="donut1" style="width: 37vw;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    Loading
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    Loading
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Tables are not supposed to be used for layout. Here is a detailed explanation as to why https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/6037