# How to divide bootstrap row into 5 equal parts?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to divide `bootstrap` row into *5 equal parts*. It includes `12-col-md`, so how i can divide it into equal 5 parts?

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Five equal columns in twitter bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387740/five-equal-columns-in-twitter-bootstrap)

Answer (score 22):

A great way to resolve this is [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20161119031859/http://www.wearesicc.com/quick-tips-5-column-layout-with-twitter-bootstrap/)!

> By default Bootstrap does not provide grid system that allows us to
> create five columns layout, but as you can see it’s quite simple. At
> first you need to create default column definition in the way that
> Bootstrap do it. I called my classes col-..-15.
>
> ```
> .col-xs-15,
> .col-sm-15,
> .col-md-15,
> .col-lg-15 {
>     position: relative;
>     min-height: 1px;
>     padding-right: 10px;
>     padding-left: 10px;
> }
> ```
>
> Next you need to define width of new classes in case of different
> media queries.
>
> ```
> .col-xs-15 {
>     width: 20%;
>     float: left;
> }
> @media (min-width: 768px) {
> .col-sm-15 {
>         width: 20%;
>         float: left;
>     }
> }
> @media (min-width: 992px) {
>     .col-md-15 {
>         width: 20%;
>         float: left;
>     }
> }
> @media (min-width: 1200px) {
>     .col-lg-15 {
>         width: 20%;
>         float: left;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Now you are ready to combine your classes with original Bootstrap
> classes. For example, if you would like to create div element which
> behave like five columns layout on medium screens and like four
> columns on smaller ones, you just need to use something like this:
>
> ```
> <div class="row">
>     <div class="col-md-15 col-sm-3">
>     ...
>     </div>
> </div>
> ```

Comment: Much better solution so far

Answer (score 13):

**Old bootstrap Version**

Use five divs with a class of span2 and give the first a class of offset1.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2 offset1"></div>
    <div class="span2"></div>
    <div class="span2"></div>
    <div class="span2"></div>
    <div class="span2"></div>
</div>
```

Five equally spaced and centered columns.

---

In bootstrap 3.0 and 4 alpha.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
</div>
```

---

**CUSTOM STYLE**

Custom Styles

```
.container {width:100%; float:left;}
.col1{ width:20%; float:left}
```

Latest Table style

```
.container {width:100%;display:table;}
.col1{ width:20%; display:table-cell;}
```

Comment: use offset-md-1 instead of col-md-offset-1 in bootstrap4.

Answer (score 5):

it is quite simple if you are using bootstrap 4, not sure if it also works in bootstrap 3

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<h2>Bootstrap 4 Five Columns</h2>
<h5>Full-width (within .container-fluid)</h5>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <img src="//placehold.it/640x480" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    <div class="col">

    </div>
    <div class="col">

    </div>
    <div class="col">

    </div>
    <div class="col">

    </div>
    <div class="col">

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
</div>
```

the first container will have offset so you will have the same margin (col-sm-1) on the left and right side with 5 equal containers inside.

Comment: @RaviDelixan has the same answer but with more options and content

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `row-cols-*` (eg: `row-cols-3`, `row-cols-md-3`) class for your requirement.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-cols-2">
    <div class="col">Column</div>
    <div class="col">Column</div>
    <div class="col">Column</div>
    <div class="col">Column</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

for more details [Visit to official bootstrap site](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/#row-columns)

Answer (score 2):

```
 <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-7">
             <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-md-4 bg-danger">1</div>
                 <div class="col-md-4 bg-success">2</div>
                 <div class="col-md-4 bg-danger">3</div>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-5">
                <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 bg-success">4</div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 bg-danger">5</div>
                    </div>
         </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: 7/3 != 5/2  , sorry

Answer (score 1):

You can use bootstrap-4 default 'col' property to solve this issue.

```
<div class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```

This will auto divide the given space into 5 equal parts.

Note: This can create issues in case if you want to show 3 columns on any other screen. Let's say if you want to show 5 columns in a row on medium screens then you can add class "col-md" on each element. But if you need 3 columns in a row on sm screens then you will face issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `span2` to utilize maximum amount of space.
Please find the code:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2">1</div>
    <div class="span2">2</div>
    <div class="span2">3</div>
    <div class="span2">4</div>
    <div class="span2">5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this css property in your custromScript.css file to use in large Device

```
    .col-lg-2-0 {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      padding-right: 15px;
      padding-left: 15px;
      -ms-flex: 0 0 20%;
      flex: 0 0 20%;
      max-width: 20%;
    }
```

and use class `col-lg-2-0` instead of `col-lg-2` which will divide four columns

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the css of bootstrap. You need import the scss files in a your own custom.scss file. Then you have to use compile custom.scss to css in another file. For ex: custom.css. Checkout this link for more detailed information.
[Bootstrap Theming](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/theming/)

In custom.scss file

```
$grid-columns:15;
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Then you can use col-{breakpoint}-3 in your project to have 5 equal width columns.

**CAREFUL**

This will be global. You have to change other files too if you have used default 12 point grid system elsewhere in your project.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to use table instead of bootstrap for dividing it into 5 parts and inside each column again you can use bootstrap grid.

This answer may help you [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62106349/8312597)

But if you have any other issues that you can't go with the above way please comment below.