# 5 equal length col in react-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I know how to make it work in plain [bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29092600/how-to-divide-bootstrap-row-into-5-equal-parts), but I was wondering how to make five columns of equal length using react-bootstrap. I tried using the same technique as I'd use in plain bootstrap, but it doesn't work. I want to make something like this but instead of six, I need five columns.

Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sTTc.png)

Comment: What technics do you use in the plain bootstrap?

Comment: please provide the code that didn't work and more information on how it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use div html elements with classes instead of Col and define specific styling for them