# Making responsive images at center by using bootstrap

Tags: html, css

```
 <img class="img-responsive center-block"/>

   <div class="col-sm-2 mb-xs-30 wow fadeInUp">
    <div class="team-item">
         <div class="team-item-image">
               <img src="images/team/jy.png" alt="" />
```

[image]

I am trying to make all the images be located at center. However, I do not know which bootstrap code I should use.
I tried to use img-responsive at the top of the section, but failed.
The given code is part of the images which is the first box I gave.

Comment: are you using bootstrap v3 or v4? And I don't think center-block will work when img-responsive is used.

Comment: without bootstrap you  can make img responsive `img:max-width:100%` try it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Responsive image align center bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462808/responsive-image-align-center-bootstrap-3)

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you're trying to make a centered row, five equally spaced and centered columns of images and you are using bootstrap, here is a link to [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35562335/5628610).

Comment: I checked it, and when seeing it it seems like the white space on the right side is far larger than that of the left.

Comment: I see what you're saying, trying some stuff out. edit: There is a solution on Codepen, https://codepen.io/DenisDov/pen/pyjpgP

Comment: https://codepen.io/devdanpark/pen/mpjxyG
I dont know if you can see this. Here's my code but It still seems the left space is larger ()without images now)

Comment: I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: I've deleted my older comments as they do not contribute to solving your solution in the best ways, see above. The link will solve what you need it to solve but you may need to edit media queries to get it truly responsive at smaller sizes.