# 8 Columns in a row in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I need to have a row with 8 columns in a large device, but then the lower number columns in a smaller device.

The bootstrap uses the 12-grid system and by default, you have options of `col-1`, `col-2`, `col-3`, `col-4`, `col-6` and `col-12`. So, it is not possible to have a row with 8 columns.

Although there are plenty of workarounds and I've tested all manner of them (like: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20287867/8-columns-in-twitter-bootstrap) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32581073/how-to-create-8-columns-in-bootstrap-that-has-12-grid-system)), One of the up-voted StackOverflow's answers is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37192924/3881354).

Based on the mentioned answer, Although the following solution works perfectly, it does not work if I use bootstrap's predefined classes like `col-md-3`, `col-sm-4`, etc.

```
.col-xs-8r,
.col-sm-8r,
.col-md-8r,
.col-lg-8r {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.col-xs-8r {
    width: 12.5%;
    float: left;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .col-sm-8r {
        width: 12.5%;
        float: left;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .col-md-8r {
        width: 12.5%;
        float: left;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .col-lg-8r {
        width: 12.5%;
        float: left;
    }
}
```

The following code words perfectly.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8r">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

If I add another `col-sm-*` or `col-md-*`, the custom column (`col-lg-8r`) does not work.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-8r">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

PS I don't like to use the nested columns and rows workaround.

Bootstrap version: 4.4.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be easier to extend the existing Bootstrap 4.4 [row columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/#row-columns). For example...

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .row-cols-lg-8 > * {
      flex: 0 0 12.5%;
      max-width: 12.5%;
    }
}
```

8 columns on `lg`, then 6 columns below `lg`...

```
<div class="row row-cols-lg-8 row-cols-6">
    <div class="col">Column</div>
    <div class="col">Column</div>
    <div class="col">Column</div>
    ...
</div>
```

Demo: https://codeply.com/p/0H3qKEVCqz

Comment: Very nice approach ;-)

Comment: Follow-up on your example which works perfectly on its own but not in my scenario where I have two columns, then in the second column I have the `row-cols-*-*` and they seem to do nothing, they conform to the top-level grid but don't do anything themselves. Is there an issue with nesting or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's not working appears to be a CSS load order issue. If you are loading your CSS before bootstrap, it's getting overridden by BS classes. For a proof of concept, I've added a `style` tag with your CSS after the BS include in the HTML panel:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
  .col-xs-8r,
  col-sm-8r,
  .col-md-8r,
  .col-lg-8r {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
  }
  
  .col-xs-8r {
    flex: 0 0 12.5%;
  }
  
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .col-sm-8r {
      flex: 0 0 12.5%;
    }
  }
  
  @media (min-width: 992px) {
    .col-md-8r {
      flex: 0 0 12.5%;
    }
  }
  
  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .col-lg-8r {
      flex: 0 0 12.5%;
    }
  }
</style>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-8r col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    column
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-8r col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    column
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-8r col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    column
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-8r col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    column
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-8r col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    column
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-8r col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    column
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-8r col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    column
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-8r col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    column
  </div>
</div>
```

If you keep your CSS loading where it is, you can get more specific (I added `.row` before the selectors):

```css
.row .col-xs-8r,
.row .col-sm-8r,
.row .col-md-8r,
.row .col-lg-8r {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.row .col-xs-8r {
  flex: 0 0 12.5%;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .row .col-sm-8r {
    flex: 0 0 12.5%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .row .col-md-8r {
    flex: 0 0 12.5%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .row .col-lg-8r {
    flex: 0 0 12.5%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-8r col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    column
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-8r col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    column
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-8r col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    column
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-8r col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    column
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-8r col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    column
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-8r col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    column
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-8r col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    column
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-8r col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    column
  </div>
</div>
```

## IMPORTANT

On a side note, you are using Bootstrap 4 which is `flex` based. You should not be using `float` but rather `flex-basis` or the shorthand `flex` property.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it is not css loading issue because I load the bootstrap firstly. Maybe the reason is that you use `flex: 0 0 12.5%;`, but I used `width: 12.5%;`;

Comment: I tested with `flex` and was able to recreate what you were seeing - your `lg` classes not applying. I was only able to fix that by loading the CSS after BS or making it more specific with `.row`. that's what lead me to believe it's a load order issue.